# Import packages (pip) facility doesn't work on Mac

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip

probably was asked 100 times but I will try once again ( maybe will get a simple answeR)
I used the commands:
url https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py
from a mac terminal to install pip. When I am going to the IDLE shell window and I am typing :
pip3 install numpy
I am getting a syntax error even though it's supposed to work.

Can somebody explain to me what is the issue?
I am not keen on downloading Anaconda as I like to keep my environment simple enough.
I am working with a mac notebook. any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks, YK

Answer (score 0):

You cant install packages through the python idle.
Try installing numpy through your mac terminal.
If it still does not work check if pip is even installed by `pip --version` or `pip3 --version`. The reason that downloading a package in the python IDLE does not work is because the python IDLE only understands valid python code(it is a python interpreter), and because `pip3 install numpy` is not python code it does not work

Answer (score 0):

The IDLE shell window is a Python interpreter and only understand python syntax. Since `pip3 install numpy` is not valid Python, you get a syntax error. Instead, you need to open Terminal and type the command there.